# Changing image bit depth using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to change 8-bit images' bit depths to 4-bit, 2-bit depths using Matlab.
Source images are 8-bit and jpg files. I wanted to take advantage of png 'BitDepth' parameter, so first I tried to convert images into png format. Then I tried to use this parameter; but I'm getting errors. Also it's OK for me if there's a simple solution using Java libraries.

```
function [] = changeBitDepth(path, depth)
clear all; close all;
clc;
A = imread(path);
imshow(A);
imwrite(A, '~/Desktop/football.png');
B = imread('~/Desktop/football.png');
imwrite(B, '~/Desktop/bitDepthChanged.png', 'BitDepth', depth);
imfinfo('~/Desktop/bitDepthChanged.png');
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you can only have 8 or 16 bit images for standard color images. You can have different bit depth for e.g. indexed images, or grayscale images ([wiki description of png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)).

> Indexed color PNGs are allowed to have 1, 2, 4 or 8 bits per pixel by the standard; grayscale images with no alpha channel allow for 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16 bits per pixel. Everything else uses a bit depth per channel of either 8 or 16.

You could do something like this:

```
% convert to indexed image
[IND,map] = rgb2ind(A,32);
% save indexed png
imwrite(IND, map, 'test.png', 'bitdepth', 4);
```

Look [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) to know how matlab deals with indexed images.